# what is the alternative of firebug and fire-path for Mozilla Firefox for find a Xpath

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, firefox-addon

As per Automation side, QA should create a custom XPath using Mozilla Firebug and Firepath. but currently, The Firefox does not give the Support for Firebug and Firepath for the latest and older version. 
so, what is the alternative of Firebug and Firepath?

Comment: IMHO, the best alternative is to create your own XPath. How about that?  :)

Comment: yes, I do create the custom XPath but is there any alternative those two add-ons? the one I am using in chrome which is Chropath. so, any other like I that I am looking for.

Comment: @MitulParekh Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53552570/5710036

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I haven't provided you with any add-on but the solution seems very simple for me - **use Firefox inner tools:**

[image]